# How can I show that $y\in R^p$ such that $\lVert y-x\rVert >1/m$ is open when x is on complement of compact subset on $R^p$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $K \subset$ $R^p$ is compact and $x\in R^p$\ $K$.

Then, $G_m$ = {$y\in R^p$ | $\lVert y-x\rVert$$> \frac{1}{m}$ } open

I tried that Suppose $G_m$ is open and then it consists of all interior point.

But I cannot go on....

and also I supposed that $G_m$ is closed and tried to find a contradiction to the property that : It must contain all of boundary points.

But I couldn't...

How can I prove this?

Comment: Given any $y \in G_{m}$ we can construct an open ball of radius $r$ around $y$ and, provided that $0 < r < \| x - y \| - \frac{1}{m}$, this open ball is strictly contained within $G_{m}$, which shows that $G_{m}$ is open. Are you sure that $K$ is a necessary part of the problem? It seems irrelevant.

Comment: @Shai   In fact, I'm studying Heine-Borel Theorem, I'm trying to understand it and K is one of part of it...

I think I now understand the theorem thorougly. Thank you

Comment: I see! If the problem as set was designed by someone then $K$ might have been a red herring. But since this problem arose in the course of your own thinking then it is up for us to decide what is relevant for the problem and what is not relevant. I think that any set of the form $G_{m}$ will be open because it is the complement of the closed ball $$C_{m} = \left\{ y \in \mathbb{R}^{p} | \| y - x \| \leq \frac{1}{m} \right\}$$ regardless of the location of $x$

Comment: @Shai Can I ask what 'red herring' is???

Comment: Sorry - I really shouldn't use idioms on the internet! A 'red herring' is a piece of information which is not necessary for the solution of a problem but which compels your attention anyway. As a stupid example: 'given that the universe is finite, what is $2+2$?' The size of the universe has no effect on the answer $4$, but the fact that the information is there makes you think you need to use it for some reason!

Comment: @Shai lol I didn't know that. Sorry for my english... T_T

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37701/discussion-between-shai-and-jaemto).